# Hide the scrollbar behind fixed positioned div

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I'm building an app in Webkit for Android using HTML and CSS. I have fixed position header and sometimes fixed position footer(based on the module). When the content is more, I don't want the scrollbar to overlay the fixed header. Hiding it behind the header will also work. How can I achieve this without fixing height for the wrapper or using `height: calc();` CSS for the wrapper?

I want app scrollbar to be like this:

[image: I want app scrollbar to be like this]

Instead, it is like this now:

[image: Instead, it is like this]

Here is the sample code:

```
.header {
position: fixed;
background-color: red;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 999; 
height: 60px;
}
.wrapper {
    padding-top: 60px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: grey;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sunrays/9hy6ybsz/)

Comment: Rather than putting all of the content in the body, put it in the content container so that users will scroll the container rather than the whole page

Comment: `.wrapper` is the content container. I don't want to fix height for it.

Comment: No, what I mean is create a content container in the wrapper (this will set apart content from navbar) so that the content scrolls rather than the page

Answer (score 1):

You said that you don't want to fixe the `.wrapper`height, but I think, you should fixe it, because there is no way to hide this scrollbar behind the `div` header element.

```
.wrapper {
    margin-top: 60px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 320px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9hy6ybsz/4/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if my solution gonna work for you. You need to setup the height of your div="wrapper" and add CSS property overflow-y:

```
height: calc(100% - (60px + 50px));
```

Example, where 60px is the header height and 50px is the footer height

```
.wrapper {
    margin-top: 60px;    
    overflow: auto;
    background: yellow;        
    height: calc(100% - (60px + 50px));
    display:block;
}
```

**Working JSFiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/9hy6ybsz/1/**

Comment: I don't want height to be fixed for body content i.e., wrapper as I have mentioned in the question. Because this app is for mobile devices of various sizes.

Comment: No problem :) Just use the calc. height: calc(100% - (60px + 50px));
http://jsfiddle.net/9hy6ybsz/5/
I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Mike I'll use height:calc(); as last resort. I was expecting some CSS3 hack but it seems there are none available.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new div tag , which acts as a parent tag.
and apply scroll for it.
then create the header div and maintain Fixed position.so you can get the scroll over the fixed DIV!